# is it possible for SQLite conncet to ftp file?

Tags: c, sqlite, ftp

I want to connect to a file on my ftp server.
I can download the db file by wget:

```
wget ftp://hello:world@192.168.137.181:21/test.db
```

my is as follows:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sqlite3.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   sqlite3 *db;
   char *zErrMsg = 0;
   int  rc;
   char *sql;
   sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_URI,1);
   /* Open database */
   rc = sqlite3_open_v2("ftp://hello:world@192.168.137.181:21/test.db", &db,  SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY | SQLITE_OPEN_URI , NULL);
   if( rc ){
      fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      exit(0);
   }else{
      fprintf(stdout, "Opened database successfully\n");
   }
```

but it showed the error:
Can't open database: unable to open database file

if I change ftp URI to a local db file path,it will work perfectly fine. so how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Why don't you read [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) before asking?